# Crontab configuration issue on CentOS?

Tags: centos, cron

I have scheduled a cron job in my CentOS server to run last night at 8.00PM, it just calling a URL and dump the output in to a file. So what I did in my crontab looks like below,

```
* 20 * * wed root curl http://www.something.com/index/exportcustomers?delta=1 >> /home/myuser/logs/cron_customer.log
```

So I expected this to run once at 8PM Wednesday (Last night). But I found that it had ran every minute for an hour. Means it had started at 8.00PM and ran every minute till 9.00PM and stopped.

I just want this to be start at 8.00PM and it should call the url once and then it should stop, that's it. To do that what that I'm doing wrong in my crontab config?

Comment: Any one need more details on this one, I cannot see much people looked in to my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, I think the correct cron syntax should be:

```
0 20 * * wed root curl http://www.something.com/index/exportcustomers?delta=1 >> /home/myuser/logs/cron_customer.log
```

Hope this helps ~!